# How to obtain list of AUC and SE after MICE (used for pool_auc in psfmi package)?

Tags: r, auc, r-mice

I have used the`mice` package to obtain 20 imputed datasets.
Then I used the function `with` in order to have one model for one dataset, then I used `pool` function in order to have the pooled model. Please find my code:

```r
IMP2 <- mice(Baseline_SEL,
             defaultMethod = c("norm", "logreg", "polyreg"),
             vis = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 6, 12),
             maxit = 20, seed = 189, m = 20,
             pred = pre)

List_fit1 <- with(data = IMP2,
                  expr = glm(formula = Echec~INCLUSIONSITE + FIB_SEVERE + Agec + SEX + DG_USE + LIV_CL + IN_COUPLE +geno3_vsOt,
                             family = binomial(link = "logit")))
summary(pool(List_fit0_Incsite), conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE)

# Comparison of nested model

List_fit1_minusdg_use <- with(data = IMP2,
                              expr = glm(formula = Echec~INCLUSIONSITE + FIB_SEVERE + Agec + SEX  + LIV_CL + IN_COUPLE +geno3_vsOt,
                                         family = binomial(link = "logit")))
D3(List_fit1, List_fit1_minusdg_use)
```

So I used the LR test in order to compare the model.

But now, for the model, I would like to pool all the AUC obtain for each dataset in order to obtain the goodness of fit of the pooled model. I have found `psfmi::pool_auc`, but I cannot find how to use it. In particular, I didn't find how to obtain the list of AUC and SE after the multiple imputation.

Do you have an idea, how to get these 2 lists?

Comment: Based on `List_fit1`, you could write a `for`-loop or use `lapply` to calculate the `se` and the `auc` per imputed dataset. Usually the easiest way to do these things is to consider how you would do it for one dataset, and then simply loop over the imputed datasets.

Answer (score 0):

See this vignette: https://mwheymans.github.io/psfmi/articles/psfmi_mice.html to get pooled logistic regression models after mice. Than use psfmi::pool_performance to get pooled AUC values (uses pool_auc).